# Method print does not work

Tags: java, loops, println, system.out

At first I am a beginner so sorry if this question is stupid and also sorry for my bad english.

So I've got the class "Stapel" and in it's constructor I declare two Arrays from the class "Karte" with parameters **karte(int wert,String name)**. Then comes the method **public void print**. Public void print's intention is to check if every karte was declared right.

These are the two arrays to declare:

```
Karte[][] karte = new Karte[4][15];
Karte[] extra = new Karte[16];
```

This is how i did it:

```
for(int j=0;j<4;j++){

        for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
            String a, b;
            if(j==0){a = "Schwert";}
            else if(j==1){a = "Kolben";}
            else if(j==2){a = "Münze";}
            else{a = "Stab";}
            if(i==11){b=" Commander";}
            else if(i==12){b=" Mistress";}
            else if(i==13){b=" Master";}
            else if(i==14){b=" Ass";}
            else{b="";}

            karte[j][i] = new Karte(i+1, a+b);

        }
```

extra[] was declared the same kind of way...

This is my method print;

```
public void print(){

    for(int j=0;j<4;j++){

        for(int i=0;i<15;i++){

            System.out.println(karte[j][i].name);
            System.out.println(karte[j][i].wert);
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){

        System.out.println(extra[i].name);
        System.out.println(extra[i].wert);
        System.out.println("");

    }
    for(int i=2;i<4;i++){

        System.out.println(extra[i].name);
        System.out.println(extra[i].wert);
        System.out.println(""); 

    }
    for(int i=4;i<6;i++){

        System.out.println(extra[i].name);
        System.out.println(extra[i].wert);
        System.out.println("");

    }
    for(int i=6;i<8;i++){

        System.out.println(extra[i].name);
        System.out.println(extra[i].wert);
        System.out.println("");

    }
    for(int i=8;i<10;i++){

        System.out.println(extra[i].name);
        System.out.println(extra[i].wert);
        System.out.println("");

    }
    for(int i=10;i<12;i++){

        System.out.println(extra[i].name);
        System.out.println(extra[i].wert);
        System.out.println("");

    }
    for(int i=12;i<14;i++){

        System.out.println(extra[i].name);
        System.out.println(extra[i].wert);
        System.out.println("");

    }
    for(int i=14;i<16;i++){

        System.out.println(extra[i].name);
        System.out.println(extra[i].wert);
        System.out.println("");

    }

}
```

My problem now is that print does not completely it's job. This is the output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4xSw.png)

As you see the first half of the method print is not working but the second half is. Why is that and how can I fix it?

The interesting thing is: The code for declaration works as it should. I know that because the program i'm using has a object inspector and it shows me the correct objects with correct values. just the print method is not working.

Thx for any help!

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I don't think your constructor is doing what you think it is. It looks to me like you've put the contents of a main method in the constructor.

Comment: One other thing: posting images of code and errors is frowned upon here, because it makes it more difficult for us to help you with your issue.  It is always better to copy and paste the relevant code and/or errors into your question directly.  Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), then [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that it works correctly but you didn't see all output.
I run your code and get results with "Schwert" and rest

```
Schwert
1

Schwert
2

Schwert
3

Schwert
4

Schwert
5

Schwert
6

Schwert
7

Schwert
8

Schwert
9

Schwert
10

Schwert
11

Schwert Commander
12

Schwert Mistress
13

Schwert Master
14

Schwert Ass
15

Kolben
1

Kolben
2

Kolben
3

Kolben
4

Kolben
5

Kolben
6

Kolben
7

Kolben
8

Kolben
9

Kolben
10

Kolben
11

Kolben Commander
12

Kolben Mistress
13

Kolben Master
14

Kolben Ass
15

Münze
1

Münze
2

Münze
3

Münze
4

Münze
5

Münze
6

Münze
7

Münze
8

Münze
9

Münze
10

Münze
11

Münze Commander
12

Münze Mistress
13

Münze Master
14

Münze Ass
15

Stab
1

Stab
2

Stab
3

Stab
4

Stab
5

Stab
6

Stab
7

Stab
8

Stab
9

Stab
10

Stab
11

Stab Commander
12

Stab Mistress
13

Stab Master
14

Stab Ass
15

Der Narr
0

Der Narr
0

Königin der Luft
-2

Königin der Finsternis
-2

Die Ausdauer
-8

Die Ausdauer
-8

Balance
-11

Balance
-11

Der Tod
-13

Der Tod
-13

Die Mäßigung
-14

Die Mäßigung
-14

Das Böse
-15

Das Böse
-15

Der Stern
-17

Der Stern
-17
```

For me it look like you need to move sidebar to see whole output :)

I made Karte class, maybe you have important differences here ?

```
public class Karte {

  int wert;
  String name;

  public Karte(int wert, String name) {
    this.wert = wert;
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```

Comment: Ok so it does work. Great! I looked the preferences of the output and there where limits in the number of bars that get showed to me. Thanks for your help!